# Auth::check fails in middleware

Tags: laravel, middleware

Can somebody explain why this strange behavior of Laravel is happening? Basically, I am trying to create a middleware for my application

```
 public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (auth()->check()) {

            $expires = Carbon::now()->addMinute(2);
            \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::put('user-is-online-' . Auth::user()->id, true, $expires);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

But `auth()->check` it is keep failing and not returning true , (user is authenticated) , auth()->check is working in other places like web routes and controllers method but why not here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `auth` middleware to protect your routes, then make sure this `auth` middleware is set to run before your middleware, otherwise `auth()->check()` will return `false`. Try `php artisan route:list` and check the orders of middlewares for your specified route.